# Cannot edit fields again on Developer Story

Tags: bug, developer-story, user-experience

**Detected on:** Stack Overflow

**When:** Editing *Developer story* on *Story view*; after performing an edit on any of the boxes by using the top right gear icon.

**What Happens:** Once I make some edits and save, the previously mentioned top right gear icon is no longer there, so I need to reload the page or do some extra navigation for it to reappear

**Expected Behavior:** After making an edit the top right gear must still be there so that I can edit (yes again) the box

Comment: Yup, I keep on having this problem too...